# Business Objects Complex prompt - how best to set up, using 4.0?

Tags: business-objects

We're trying to create a template date prompt to be used across multiple universes, and also be used against multiple date fields (for instance, Transaction Date, Invoice Date, etc)

The prompt should display a list of values like the below (there's about 30 total):

```
Date Range           START_DATE                     END_DATE
-------------------- ------------------------------ --------------
D: Yesterday         12/02/2015                     12/03/2015
M: Month Before Last 10/01/2015                     10/31/2015
M: Month to Date     12/01/2015                     12/02/2015
```

Our initial attempt at this (creating a derived table, and then some aliases against the derived table, with one alias for each date type such as Transaction Date, Invoice Date, etc) was a failure - the sql generated is wrong, and includes the sql that's just supposed to provide the list of values. I think we need to use a different approach entirely.

Thanks for reading so far. I would greatly appreciate any ideas! Feel free to ask questions and I'll edit my notes to answer.

EDIT - we're using UNV (legacy Universe Design tool)

Comment: Which type of universe are you using, UNX or UNV?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kristof - we're using UNV (legacy universe design tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have an existing (dimension) table that contains a record for each date and the necessary columns to hold the different representations. You can also create a derived table for this.

Here are the steps to achieve what you described (sorry, no screenshots, this is off the top of my head):

1. Create the required dimension objects (based on your date table) in a separate class in the universe (you can hide this class at the end; the end user shouldn't see them).
2. Take one of the date dimension objects (e.g. Transaction Date, Invoice Date. …), enable the LOV option and edit it (which should bring up the query panel).
3. In the query panel, select all the dimension objects, created in step 1, that you want to show in your LOV. Important: the object holding the value to be returned, should be placed first in the query panel. Run the query (nothing will appear though).
4. Make sure that you enable the option to *Export the LOV*, otherwise your customisations will be lost upon exporting the universe. Optionally, enable the option to refresh the LOV each time the user calls it.

As you can't really define a single, reusable LOV in UDT that you can reference in different dimension objects, you'll have to perform this *for each* dimension object that you would want to have this LOV.

One way around this annoyance *may* to define the customised LOV once, note down the generated LOV name (about 8 alphanumeric characters long) and then replace the LOV name in the other dimensions with that LOV name. I'm can't guarantee that this will work though.

In contrast: with IDT you can define a customised LOV like this once (either in the Data Foundation Layer or the Business Layer), and then reference it as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kristof. One question - should this still work considering that the prompt/LOV should actually return 2 values, the start date and end date for the particular date period (for instance, Month Before Last would return 10/01/2015 and 10/31/2015, which would form the beginning and end of the "between"

Comment: While a multi-value prompt can return multiple values (rows), you cannot return multiple values (in separate columns).